# Capture the last rendered response and access in backing bean

Tags: jsf

I have a multi-step signup wizard whereby the users progress is tracked as they progress through each step in the wizard and saved to the database on every AJAX request (the entire signup process consists of about 10-20 AJAX updates and finishes with a POST)

If a user does not complete the signup process we would like to see the rendered view at the point at which they left, this would require us to capture and overwrite the rendered response after each request, when the users signup state is saved we could then store their last response as a string.

I am just trying to figure out the best way to achieve this, using a `PhaseListener` at RenderResponse stage or would we need a `Filter` to capture the raw output? Presumably we could then store output in the Page/Conversation scope so it survives the next request?

Comment: Are you aware that a JSF ajax response does normally not represent a whole HTML document? I would guess that you'd actually rather like to "capture" the whole HTML document as it is in client side.

Comment: Yes I was only expecting to capture the newly rendered components (although capturing the entire document would be a bonus)

Comment: OK. The 1st dupe answers your concrete quesiton and the 2nd dupe answers your bonus question.